# Why is there no margin on right side?

Tags: html, css

[instead of having a margin of the right side because of the margin placed on .nav, it just covers the whole area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgSYW.png)

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--secondary);
    color: var(--font-color);
    background-image: url(3ca749da0b938c6392de6488c28b11c8.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5 14 5 14 ;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 7;
    overflow-x:
}
```

Comment: add the whole html code as a html snippet.

Comment: because you need to add unit, unitless numbers are invalid

Comment: @fedesc — They have already (but that puts padding inside the width, not margin).

Comment: @Quentin Oh haven't noticed the `*`

Comment: @fatalcoder524 what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

1. Your CSS is [invalid](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). Lengths require **units** unless they are `0`.
2. With a width of `100%` the left margin will apply, push the element to the right, then the right-hand edge and right margin will be off-screen to the right.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
1. I already put px on the units but doesn't fix the problem.
2. I made it into 98% and it looks like the left side, but when i shrink the browser the right margin can't be found again. 

is it just a normal thing? or just on me?
again, thank you for answering.

Comment: Also, no matter what margin i put on the right side, it doesnt change. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Because you have a fixed (relative to the screen) width. Changing it to 98 just gives you a *different* fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any scale for your margins try putting:

```
nav { 
         margin: 5px 14px 5px 14px;
      }
```

Comment: That's invalid. You can't have a space between the number and unit of a length, and there shouldn't be a comma in the middle of the margin value.

Comment: It was a typo, fixed. it.

Comment: I did that but doesn't fix the problem. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: can you try, putting width to auto:

Answer (score -1):

this is applying to all you haven't noticed the * `*{margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box; }`
firstly remove this and add unit like this `nav{margin: 5px 14px 5px 14px;}`

Comment: Tried both but there's always no right margin. Thanks btw.

Comment: did you fixed ? add overflow:hidden;